# How do I automatically format a segment of code?

Tags: regex, xml, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am currently trying out .xdxf format files, which I believe inserts itself in XML, and I am building a bilingual dictionary for an university class.
I am building this .xdxf file from a .txt file which compiles all the dictionary entries, around 300. This is how an entry is displayed before any coding:

```
meat:carne
```

And after adding the elements:

```
<ar><k>meat</k><def>carne</def></ar>
```

And this is how I want it to look:

```
<ar>
  <k>meat</k>
  <def>
    carne
  </def>
</ar>
```

Is there any way I can do this automatically? I will never see the end of this if I do it one by one.
Thanks!

Comment: In Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 you can select Edit > Advanced and select either "Format Document" or "Format Selection". Is there a similar option available for you?

Comment: Thanks, I already found a solution! Doesn't work on Visual Studio Code but it does on Notepad++. Basically you use find replace to do it, you select "use regular expressions" and then find (.*):(.*) and replace with <ar>\n\t<k>\1<\k>\n\t<def>\n\t\t\2\n\t</def><\ar> ! But thanks anyways :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do some *find-and-replace* using regular expression with Visual Studio Code.

- hit `CTRL + H` on Windows
- click on the button `.*` located at the right of the "Find" control
- in the "Find" control, enter `(.*):(.*)`
- in the "Replace" control enter `<ar>\n\t<k>$1</k>\n\t<def>\n\t\t$2\n\t</def>\n</ar>`
- press the "Replace All" button

[image]